# Math from extended class being ignored?

Tags: java, integer

Have been working with this code for a couple days and cannot figure out why the skills are not using the math I assigned in Attributes.java

If I allocate 5 points to Intelligence, then Science should compute to 60.
Instead science is computing to 30.
I think the program is using the original 5 points it was set at for the calculation, instead of the upgraded 10?

Attributes.java

```
public class Attributes {
    static int strength = 5;
    static int perception = 5;
    static int endurance = 5;
    static int charisma = 5;
    static int intelligence = 5;
    static int agility = 5;
    static int luck = 5;
    static int hitpoints = ((endurance * 4) + (strength));
    static int armorClass = (endurance + 1);
    static int actionPoints = (agility + 1);
    static int carryWeight = ((strength * 30) + 5);
    static int meleeDamage = (strength / 2);
    static int damageResis = (endurance + 1);
    static int poisonResis = (endurance * 5);
    static int radResis = (endurance * 2);
    static int sequence = (perception + agility);
    static int healingRate = (endurance / 2);
    static int criticalChance = (((luck * 2) + (agility / 3)) + 1);
    static int smallGuns = ((perception + agility + luck) * 2);
    static int bigGuns = (((strength / 2) + (perception / 2) + agility + luck) * 2);
    static int energyWeapons = (((intelligence / 2)+ (perception / 2) + agility + luck) * 2);
    static int unarmed = (((strength / 2) + (perception / 2) + (agility / 2) + (endurance / 2) + luck) * 2);
    static int meleeWeapons = (((strength / 2) + (perception / 2) + (agility / 2) + (endurance / 2) + luck) * 2);
    static int throwing = (((strength / 2) + (perception / 2) + agility + luck) * 2);
    static int firstAid = (((intelligence * 2) + perception) * 2);
    static int doctor = ((intelligence * 3) * 2);
    static int sneak = (((perception / 2) + (luck / 2) + (agility * 2)) * 2);
    static int lockpick = (((perception / 2) + (luck / 2) + agility + intelligence) * 2);
    static int steal = (((perception / 2) + (luck / 2) + (agility * 2)) * 2);
    static int traps = (((perception / 2) + (luck / 2) + agility + intelligence) * 2);
    static int science = ((intelligence * 3) * 2);
    static int repair = (((agility / 2) + (perception / 2) + (intelligence * 2)) * 2);
    static int speech = ((intelligence + (charisma * 2)) * 2);
    static int barter = ((intelligence + (charisma * 2)) * 2);
    static int gambling = ((luck * 3) * 2);
    static int outdoors = (((strength / 2) + (agility / 2) + (intelligence / 2) + (luck / 2) + endurance) * 2);
}
```

Game.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game extends Attributes{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String enter = "Press Enter to continue.";
        String name = null;
        int age = 0;
        String gender = null;
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("     *** Welcome to Fallout! ***");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Press Enter to begin character creation.");
        Scanner pressEnter = new Scanner(System.in);
        pressEnter.nextLine();

        Scanner nameScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is your name?");
        name = nameScan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Greetings " + name + "!");
        System.out.println();

        Scanner ageScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How old are you?");
        while (ageScan.hasNextInt()) {
            age = ageScan.nextInt();
            if ((age <= 82) && (age >=18))
            break;
        else System.out.println("Please choose a number between 18 & 82");
        }
        System.out.println(age + ". Got it.");
        System.out.println();
        Scanner genderScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Are you Male or Female?");
        while (genderScan.hasNextLine()) {
            gender = genderScan.nextLine();
            if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("Male") || gender.equalsIgnoreCase("Female"))
                break;
            else System.out.println("Please choose Male or Female");
        }
        System.out.println(gender + ". Noted.");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(enter);
        pressEnter.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Your Attributes are as follows:");
        System.out.println("Strength: " + strength);
        System.out.println("Perception: " + perception);
        System.out.println("Endurance: " + endurance);
        System.out.println("Charisma: " + charisma);
        System.out.println("Intelligence: " + intelligence);
        System.out.println("Agility: " + agility);
        System.out.println("Luck: " + luck);
        System.out.println(enter);
        pressEnter.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("You have 5 attribute points to allocate.");
        System.out.println("What would you like to increase?");
        System.out.println("Strength, Perception, Endurance, Charisma, Intelligence, Agility or Luck?");
        Scanner scanFirstPoint = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputFirstPoint = null;
        while (scanFirstPoint.hasNextLine()) {
            inputFirstPoint = scanFirstPoint.nextLine();
            if (inputFirstPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Strength") || inputFirstPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Perception") ||
                    inputFirstPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Endurance") || inputFirstPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Charisma")
                    || inputFirstPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Intelligence") ||
                    inputFirstPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Agility") || inputFirstPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Luck"))
                break;
            else System.out.println("Please choose Strength, Perception, Endurance, Charisma, " +
                    "Intelligence, Agility or Luck");
        }
        if (inputFirstPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Strength")) {
            System.out.println("Strength Increased by 1!");
            strength ++;
            System.out.println("Strength: " + strength);
        } else if (inputFirstPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Perception")) {
            System.out.println("Perception Increased by 1!");
            perception ++;
            System.out.println("Perception: " + perception);
        } else if (inputFirstPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Endurance")) {
            System.out.println("Endurance Increased by 1!");
            endurance ++;
            System.out.println("Endurance: " + endurance);
        } else if (inputFirstPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Charisma")) {
            System.out.println("Charisma Increased by 1!");
            charisma ++;
            System.out.println("Charisma: " + charisma);
        } else if (inputFirstPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Intelligence")) {
            System.out.println("Intelligence Increased by 1!");
            intelligence ++;
            System.out.println("Intelligence: " + intelligence);
        } else if (inputFirstPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Agility")) {
            System.out.println("Agility Increased by 1!");
            agility ++;
            System.out.println("Agility: " + agility);
        } else if (inputFirstPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Luck")) {
            System.out.println("Luck Increased by 1!");
            luck ++;
            System.out.println("Luck: " + luck);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("You have 4 attribute points to allocate.");
        System.out.println("What would you like to increase?");
        System.out.println("Strength, Perception, Endurance, Charisma, Intelligence, Agility or Luck?");
        Scanner scanSecondPoint = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputSecondPoint = null;
        while (scanSecondPoint.hasNextLine()) {
            inputSecondPoint = scanSecondPoint.nextLine();
            if (inputSecondPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Strength") || inputSecondPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Perception") ||
                    inputSecondPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Endurance") || inputSecondPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Charisma")
                    || inputSecondPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Intelligence") ||
                    inputSecondPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Agility") || inputSecondPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Luck"))
                break;
            else System.out.println("Please choose Strength, Perception, Endurance, Charisma, " +
                    "Intelligence, Agility or Luck");
        }
        if (inputSecondPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Strength")) {
            System.out.println("Strength Increased by 1!");
            strength ++;
            System.out.println("Strength: " + strength);
        } else if (inputSecondPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Perception")) {
            System.out.println("Perception Increased by 1!");
            perception ++;
            System.out.println("Perception: " + perception);
        } else if (inputSecondPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Endurance")) {
            System.out.println("Endurance Increased by 1!");
            endurance ++;
            System.out.println("Endurance: " + endurance);
        } else if (inputSecondPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Charisma")) {
            System.out.println("Charisma Increased by 1!");
            charisma ++;
            System.out.println("Charisma: " + charisma);
        } else if (inputSecondPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Intelligence")) {
            System.out.println("Intelligence Increased by 1!");
            intelligence ++;
            System.out.println("Intelligence: " + intelligence);
        } else if (inputSecondPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Agility")) {
            System.out.println("Agility Increased by 1!");
            agility ++;
            System.out.println("Agility: " + agility);
        } else if (inputSecondPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Luck")) {
            System.out.println("Luck Increased by 1!");
            luck ++;
            System.out.println("Luck: " + luck);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("You have 3 attribute points to allocate.");
        System.out.println("What would you like to increase?");
        System.out.println("Strength, Perception, Endurance, Charisma, Intelligence, Agility or Luck?");
        Scanner scanThirdPoint = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputThirdPoint = null;
        while (scanThirdPoint.hasNextLine()) {
            inputThirdPoint = scanThirdPoint.nextLine();
            if (inputThirdPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Strength") || inputThirdPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Perception") ||
                    inputThirdPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Endurance") || inputThirdPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Charisma")
                    || inputThirdPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Intelligence") ||
                    inputThirdPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Agility") || inputThirdPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Luck"))
                break;
            else System.out.println("Please choose Strength, Perception, Endurance, Charisma, " +
                    "Intelligence, Agility or Luck");
        }
        if (inputThirdPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Strength")) {
            System.out.println("Strength Increased by 1!");
            strength ++;
            System.out.println("Strength: " + strength);
        } else if (inputThirdPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Perception")) {
            System.out.println("Perception Increased by 1!");
            perception ++;
            System.out.println("Perception: " + perception);
        } else if (inputThirdPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Endurance")) {
            System.out.println("Endurance Increased by 1!");
            endurance ++;
            System.out.println("Endurance: " + endurance);
        } else if (inputThirdPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Charisma")) {
            System.out.println("Charisma Increased by 1!");
            charisma ++;
            System.out.println("Charisma: " + charisma);
        } else if (inputThirdPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Intelligence")) {
            System.out.println("Intelligence Increased by 1!");
            intelligence ++;
            System.out.println("Intelligence: " + intelligence);
        } else if (inputThirdPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Agility")) {
            System.out.println("Agility Increased by 1!");
            agility ++;
            System.out.println("Agility: " + agility);
        } else if (inputThirdPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Luck")) {
            System.out.println("Luck Increased by 1!");
            luck ++;
            System.out.println("Luck: " + luck);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("You have 2 attribute points to allocate.");
        System.out.println("What would you like to increase?");
        System.out.println("Strength, Perception, Endurance, Charisma, Intelligence, Agility or Luck?");
        Scanner scanFourthPoint = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputFourthPoint = null;
        while (scanFourthPoint.hasNextLine()) {
            inputFourthPoint = scanFourthPoint.nextLine();
            if (inputFourthPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Strength") || inputFourthPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Perception") ||
                    inputFourthPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Endurance") || inputFourthPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Charisma")
                    || inputFourthPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Intelligence") ||
                    inputFourthPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Agility") || inputFourthPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Luck"))
                break;
            else System.out.println("Please choose Strength, Perception, Endurance, Charisma, " +
                    "Intelligence, Agility or Luck");
        }
        if (inputFourthPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Strength")) {
            System.out.println("Strength Increased by 1!");
            strength ++;
            System.out.println("Strength: " + strength);
        } else if (inputFourthPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Perception")) {
            System.out.println("Perception Increased by 1!");
            perception ++;
            System.out.println("Perception: " + perception);
        } else if (inputFourthPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Endurance")) {
            System.out.println("Endurance Increased by 1!");
            endurance ++;
            System.out.println("Endurance: " + endurance);
        } else if (inputFourthPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Charisma")) {
            System.out.println("Charisma Increased by 1!");
            charisma ++;
            System.out.println("Charisma: " + charisma);
        } else if (inputFourthPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Intelligence")) {
            System.out.println("Intelligence Increased by 1!");
            intelligence ++;
            System.out.println("Intelligence: " + intelligence);
        } else if (inputFourthPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Agility")) {
            System.out.println("Agility Increased by 1!");
            agility ++;
            System.out.println("Agility: " + agility);
        } else if (inputFourthPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Luck")) {
            System.out.println("Luck Increased by 1!");
            luck ++;
            System.out.println("Luck: " + luck);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("You have 1 attribute points to allocate.");
        System.out.println("What would you like to increase?");
        System.out.println("Strength, Perception, Endurance, Charisma, Intelligence, Agility or Luck?");
        Scanner scanFifthPoint = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputFifthPoint = null;
        while (scanFifthPoint.hasNextLine()) {
            inputFifthPoint = scanFifthPoint.nextLine();
            if (inputFifthPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Strength") || inputFifthPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Perception") ||
                    inputFifthPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Endurance") || inputFifthPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Charisma")
                    || inputFifthPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Intelligence") ||
                    inputFifthPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Agility") || inputFifthPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Luck"))
                break;
            else System.out.println("Please choose Strength, Perception, Endurance, Charisma, " +
                    "Intelligence, Agility or Luck");
        }
        if (inputFifthPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Strength")) {
            System.out.println("Strength Increased by 1!");
            strength ++;
            System.out.println("Strength: " + strength);
        } else if (inputFifthPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Perception")) {
            System.out.println("Perception Increased by 1!");
            perception ++;
            System.out.println("Perception: " + perception);
        } else if (inputFifthPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Endurance")) {
            System.out.println("Endurance Increased by 1!");
            endurance ++;
            System.out.println("Endurance: " + endurance);
        } else if (inputFifthPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Charisma")) {
            System.out.println("Charisma Increased by 1!");
            charisma ++;
            System.out.println("Charisma: " + charisma);
        } else if (inputFifthPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Intelligence")) {
            System.out.println("Intelligence Increased by 1!");
            intelligence ++;
            System.out.println("Intelligence: " + intelligence);
        } else if (inputFifthPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Agility")) {
            System.out.println("Agility Increased by 1!");
            agility ++;
            System.out.println("Agility: " + agility);
        } else if (inputFifthPoint.equalsIgnoreCase("Luck")) {
            System.out.println("Luck Increased by 1!");
            luck ++;
            System.out.println("Luck: " + luck);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Your new attributes are:");
        System.out.println("Strength: " + strength);
        System.out.println("Perception: " + perception);
        System.out.println("Endurance: " + endurance);
        System.out.println("Charisma: " + charisma);
        System.out.println("Intelligence: " + intelligence);
        System.out.println("Agility: " + agility);
        System.out.println("Luck: " + luck);
        System.out.println(enter);
        pressEnter.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Your Skills are as follows:");
        System.out.println("Small Guns: " + smallGuns);
        System.out.println("Big Guns: " + bigGuns);
        System.out.println("Energy Weapons: " + energyWeapons);
        System.out.println("Unarmed: " + unarmed);
        System.out.println("Melee Weapons: " + meleeWeapons);
        System.out.println("Throwing: " + throwing);
        System.out.println("First Aid: " + firstAid);
        System.out.println("Doctor: " + doctor);
        System.out.println("Sneak: " + sneak);
        System.out.println("Lockpick: " + lockpick);
        System.out.println("Steal: " + steal);
        System.out.println("Traps: " + traps);
        System.out.println("Science: " + science);
        System.out.println("Repair: " + repair);
        System.out.println("Speech: " + speech);
        System.out.println("Barter: " + barter);
        System.out.println("Gambling: " + gambling);
        System.out.println("Outdoors: " + outdoors);
        System.out.println(enter);
        pressEnter.nextLine();
        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

Comment: `I allocate 5 points to Intelligence, then Science should compute to 60.` - how so if `static int science = ((intelligence * 3) * 2);`? This would result in 5 * 3 * 2 which is 30.

Comment: @Thomas I believe he meant adding 5 points to intelligence. This looks like it's related to the Fallout games

Comment: How is the rest of the code relevant?

Comment: @Thomas, you got this one! OP, you probably don't want to store this data as a bunch of static variables. This is an inflexible solution, and you should store try to store them as class members instead.

Comment: Besides that, keep in mind that you're dealing with integers and thus things `strength / 2` will be rounded down (in your case to 2 because strength is 5).

Comment: @Dragondraikk yes that might be the case. If so the OP would need to update the values accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I need 50 reputation to comment, so I'll just answer your question. Your calculated values aren't being updated when you add points to the base values. Thus you need to update all your values AFTER assigning the skill points.

EDIT: To make this clearer - Your strength, perception, endurance, intelligence, agility, charisma, and luck are all initialized to 5. Those are the only values to which you can add points to increase in value. All the rest of the values(hitpoints, science, etc) are calculated from those. However, when you choose to spend your skill points, you aren't recalculating all the other values which depend on the base values.

Comment: Don't see why this wouldn't be an answer, considering it explains the problem exactly and proposes a solution.

Comment: Jeremy Anantharaj, appreciate your answer very much! I ended up moving all my static integers to just regular integers, than removing them from the Attributes class and pasting them into the Game class. This fixed the issue.

Comment: No problemo. I'm glad you were able to find the solution from my suggestion. And @Dragondraikk thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the values after setting some intial attributes, I'd move initialization to a method and call that whenever a base attribute has been changed.

What I mean is something like this:

```
class Attributes {
  ...
  int intelligence = 5;
  ...
  int science; //will be 0 by default

  //instance initializer
  {
    update(); //initial call so that the values have their correct values
  }

  public void update() {
    ...
    science = intelligence * 3 * 2;
    ...
  }
}
```

and later:

```
Attributes a = ...


a.addIntelligence( 5 ); //add 5 so now it is 10
a.addStrength( 2 );
a.update(); //recalculates science which should now be 60
```

Note that I left out the keyword `static` since it would most probably be better design to use instances instead of static values. Feel free to add it again (also to the instance initializer) if you want.